# System requirements for an Oracle Connection Manager server

Tags: oracle, connection

I have done a PoC using Oracle Connection Manager; However, I am unable to find the system requirements for Oracle Connection Manager - I intend to setup Oracle Connection Manager on a Windows Server 2012 VM with 16 GB RAM and 2.4 GHz (2 processor) CPU - My application will only be reading data i.e. will not update / delete or insert data - Would the system requirements I plan to build be sufficient?

Comment: Why don't you ask your provider about this? Have you carefully read [ask]? Here is not exactly the kind of question that can find an answer here. Maybe dba.stackexchange.com could be better?

Comment: I searched the provider's i.e. Oracle's sites for an answer but could not find the system requirements - I have now spoken to the DBA team in my organisation if they can reach out to Oracle support and find an answer.